# PHP Variable from Database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get a variable out of my database result and to work with this result. I want to send an email using this script which I got it off the internet. I am using a MySQL database.

It is an register script, so I want to send a new email after they confirmed there e-mail. With a TeamSpeak-Key.

```
<?php
require('includes/config.php');

//collect values from the url
$memberID = trim($_GET['x']);
$active = trim($_GET['y']);

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT email FROM members WHERE memberID='$memberID'";

if(is_numeric($memberID) && !empty($active)){
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE members SET active = 'Yes' WHERE memberID = :memberID AND active = :active");
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':memberID' => $memberID,
        ':active' => $active,   
    ));

    if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){
        $to = $_POST[$e_mail];
        $subject = "Berechtigungsschlüssel";
        $body = "<p>Anbei findest du deinen Berechtigungsschlüssel</p>
            <p>function auslesen($line)</p>
            <p>Mit freundlichen Grüßen</p>
            <p>Betas.network</p>";

        $mail = new Mail();
        $mail->setFrom(SITEEMAIL);
        $mail->addAddress($e_mail);
        $mail->subject($subject);
        $mail->body($body);
        $mail->send();

        header('Location: login.php?action=active');
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "Your account could not be activated." ; 
    }
}
?>
```

The new variable has to go into:

```
$to = $_POST[$e_mail];
```

and

```
$mail->addAddress($e_mail);
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: I'm guessing it would probably be `$_POST['e_mail'];`, not `$_POST[$e_mail];`

Comment: I don't even Gott the var 

Comment: I cannot find $email defined anywhere in your code. In addition to this, you need to fetch the data and then set the $email variable along with others. Currently you are UPDATING the data and trying to use the rest of the code that is meant for SELECT. I am just guessing that you might be getting the error you have defined.